# WebSocket: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: websocket, symfony4, ratchet

I'm tring to learn about webSocket, so I use symfony and Ratchet library.

I have followed the documentation of Ratchet , I have created the Chat class and the server. **Everything works fine when I test in the linux console** , the connections are establieshed and the messages are sent to all connected clients.

But when I put this javascript code in the twig file to test it in the browser :

```
<body>
<h1>Websokets chat</h1>


<script>
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};

</script>
</body>
```

I get this erreor :

> chat:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
>   (anonymous) @ chat:8

This is the code of Command to run server:

```
<?php
namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use App\Server\Chat;

class ChatServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('hous:app:chat-server')
            ->setDescription('Start chat server');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new Chat(),
            8080,
            '127.0.0.1'
        );
        $server->run();
    }
}
```

**SOLVED:**

I have changed the code inside the server like this:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ), 8080);

    $server->run();
}
```